# Can someone help me with my ajax code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wanted to change the visibility of the thumbnail to visible right after when I click the button what should I do? please help me on this one because I cannot figure it out by myself because I do not know so much about ajax and web programming. Thanks in advance.

```js
function ha(){
 $('#tabExe').click(function(event){
   $.ajax({
      url:'backEnd/ROOMS.php',
      success:function(result){
        $('#room1').css({ // this is just for style        
          "visibility" : "visible",
        }); 
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="border-radius:0px;" type="submit" name="tabExe" onClick="function ha();" id="tabExe" href="#Exec" class="btn btn-primary">
  Executive Room
</button>
            
<div id = "rm1" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
  <a id="room1" value="sa" href="#" class="thumbnail" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../backEnd/res/img/login/roomActive.png" style="width:100px;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "I wanted to change the visibility of the thumbnail to visible right after when I click the button", do you mean you want to show the thumbnail immediately or wait until the response comes back and THEN show it?

Comment: i just want to show the thumbnail, they said i need to use ajax because when using ajax, the page wont refresh the page so any changes will stay ,. because there is this one time where i didnt use ajax and just used POST method on the button , I found out that my thumbnail becomes visible but goes hidden again right after the page refreshes because of the POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to show the thumbnail (and you're not concerned about the response), include a `beforeSend` callback, like this:

```
$('#tabExe').click(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url:'backEnd/ROOMS.php',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#room1').css({ // this is just for style        
                "visibility" : "visible",
            }); 
        },
        success:function(result){

        }
    });
});
```

This will call before making the ajax request. `success` and `error` only are called when the request completes.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/rzr5mrL1/

**EDIT:**
IF you need the thumbnail to show when a response comes back, then you'll want to look into the ajax response and see why `success` is not being called. One way to test is to add `complete`, something like this:

```
$('#tabExe').click(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url:'backEnd/ROOMS.php',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#room1').css({ // this is just for style        
                "visibility" : "visible",
            }); 
        },
        success:function(result){

        },
        complete: function(results) {
            alert(results.status);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/rzr5mrL1/1/

Should alert (404)

Good luck.

Comment: sir thank you so much, I can now make it visible ! wee im so happy, but why do i need to click the button twice to make it visible? and this error 404 pops up too

Comment: Regarding clicking twice - it's because your event binding is done within the `ha` function. Instead, as Garret suggested, you'll want to use `$(document).ready` and remove `onClick="function ha()"` As for the 404, if you added the "complete" callback, that means your ajax call is not being made (which is why success was never called) - it just validates the error with your end point (`backEnd/ROOMS.php`).

Comment: but doing that $(document) does not help, when i used onClick again, it worked.

Comment: In your `$(document).ready` call, do you still have the `click` code wrapped in the `ha` function?

Comment: btw, I removed the method (tabExe).onclick event .. after that, my code still work and i only need to press the button once! thank you so much for your idea of the beforeSend

Comment: Great! Glad to hear @RolandMendoza :)

Comment: yeah thank you so much , i could not add 1 point to ur rep cuz i only have 3 rep for now, but i marked your code as the best answer to this one ! once again, THANKS